# How to fix ' invalid identifier' - execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to run the dynamic query in the code; the string is a select that uses the input parameters of my 'archive' function: I have to select the records in the table that have an expiration date prior to the one i input in the function.
No compile error but when I try to execute it I find the error

> ORA-00904: "FEB": invalid identifier.

I've done

```
execute archivia_('4-02-2000','data_prestito','prestiti','scadenza');
```

What is the right way to chain a date type value into a string? Is it right to convert it to char?
can someone help me?

```
create or replace procedure archivia_(p_data varchar,select_arg varchar, 
   tabella varchar,colonna varchar) as

conv_data varchar(50):= to_date(p_data,'dd/mm/yyyy');

str_sql varchar(200) := 'select '||select_arg||' from ' || tabella || ' where ' || colonna || ' < ' || to_char(conv_data);

data_prestito date;
saldo int:= 0;

begin 

    execute immediate str_sql into data_prestito;
    dbms_output.put_line(data_prestito);
end;
```

Comment: There's no string "FEB" anywhere in your code; please make sure the error message matches the code you actually run.

Comment: The right way is to use parameters.  Learn about the `using` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wernfried Domscheit suggested, the ideal design should be as per the answer by him.

If, you are restricted to not to change procedure and want to pass the date in string format then make sure that the date you are passing and the formula to convert the string to date in procedure is using the same date format.

so pass the date as following while calling the procedure:

```
execute archivia_('04/02/2000','data_prestito','prestiti','scadenza');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: thanks! it works, my tutor suggested me to pass the date like a string, this confused me, I will surely deepen the topic. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I think you had accepted the other answer. I thought this answer actually resolved your issue and you should accept this one

Comment: I'm sorry the use of 'accept answer'  wasn't immediately clear to me. Both answers solve my problem differently, in the first I discovered the use of USIG with the second one I satisfied the request on the type of data to pass the date! how do you behave in this situation?

Comment: If your tutor suggested passing a date as a string, then perhaps the best answer is 'get another tutor'. IMHO Basic Rule: Dates are DATE or timestamp, id (usually) and calculation columns are NUMERIC, everything else, even if only digits, an CHARACTER type.

Comment: -.-'''' thanks! luckily for me this is just a transition moment, the best tutor I have is stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Very bad design of using DATE values. Proper design would be this one:

```
create or replace procedure archivia_(p_data DATE,select_arg varchar, 
   tabella varchar,colonna varchar) as

str_sql varchar(200) := 
   'select '||select_arg||' from ' || tabella || ' where ' || colonna || ' < :cData';

data_prestito date;
saldo int:= 0;

begin 

    execute immediate str_sql into data_prestito USING p_data;
    dbms_output.put_line(data_prestito);
end;

execute archivia_(DATE '2000-02-04','data_prestito','prestiti','scadenza');
or
execute archivia_(TO_DATE('4-02-2000', 'mm-dd-yyyy'),'data_prestito','prestiti','scadenza');
```